# MySQL server won't start with foreign_key_checks=0

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key, mysqld

I'm running Ubuntu with MySQL version 5.5.44

> mysqld  Ver 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

I have a DB with foreign keys. I would like to have the foreign key check disabled at the **system** level (not at the session).

I saw the system var [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) that seems to control this behavior but when I set it in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (by adding `foreign_key_checks = 0`) the server won't start. The error log looks like:

```
150729 15:38:18 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150729 15:38:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150729 15:38:18 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150729 15:38:18  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150729 15:38:19 InnoDB: 5.5.44 started; log sequence number 56348937
150729 15:38:19 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'foreign_key_checks=0'
150729 15:38:19 [ERROR] Aborting
```

How can I configure my MySQL server to start with foreign key checks off at the system level?

Edit: behavior is the same with MySQL 5.6.25:

> mysqld  Ver 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: Yes, I put it right after the [mysqld] line.

Comment: Yes @BK435, the behavior (and error message) is the same regardless of whether the '=' is surrounded with spaces or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Root Cause

[foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) is not a global option you can preset at startup. Why ?

When you click on that link to the Documentation on [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks), there is no chart that says it is global or session scope. Other options will specify the scope in a chart

- [ft_boolean_syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_boolean_syntax) says Variable Scope Global ; Dynamic Variable Yes
- [innodb_doublewrite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite) says Variable Scope Global ; Dynamic Variable No
- [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) says Variable Scope Global ; Dynamic Variable Yes
- [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) says Variable Scope Global,Session ; Dynamic Variable Yes

With [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks), it is session scope only.

Further proof of this is when you go to the command line and run this

```
mysqld --help --verbose > /tmp/mysqld.txt
vi /tmp/mysqld.txt
```

When you look inside the text file, you do not see `--foreign-key-checks` as a command line startup option. The other four variables I showed you can be used on the command line and in `my.cnf`.

If you have data to load, you can set that before loading:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
source mydata.sql
```

Proof of this is a standard mysqldump header ( first 10 lines )

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Please note line 8

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

What does the bottom of a mysqldump look like ? Like this:

```
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Please note the line

```
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
```

## Epilogue

Bottom Line: [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) is not meant of use in `my.cnf`. That make the most sense because (if allowed) starting mysqld with that would be damaging to referential integrity from startup.

Comment: For the same reason, `unique_checks` can only be set at runtime.